# Trying to receive all messages within a specific channel created in a different command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently coding a bot that will allow two people to play chess globally, within a server, on a single account or against a bot. Currently, my method for doing this involves a matchmaking algorithm (that isn't the most complex), then it creates a channel for the players to message in, or two channels with webhooks in on different servers in the case of a global game. My question is: How would I go about running code whenever a message is sent in one of these channels? Specifically, I need to send a copy of each message sent in one channel to the other via a webhook in a global game so both players can communicate as well as check if the input message is in the format of a move, in which case the bot would make the move as well as copying the message to the other channel. I've thought of using an

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(mes)
```

but I can't do that globally as the channels to check for messages wouldn't be known on a global scope and I don't know if it can be defined within the function in a way that can check the channel either. Thanks!

Comment: i am not familiar to the internet side of python, but would it be possible for the user to send a message to an intermediate, who messages it to all people on the channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in my_list_of_channel_ids:
        # It's a chess channel
        # Now you can check if the message contains a valid move
```

or you can use [`bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

```py
# The `is_game_over` var indicates if the game is over
while not is_game_over:
    def check(message):
        """Checks if the message contains a valid move,

        you should also check if `message.author == `ctx.author` 
        if you're doing this in a command

        and if message.channel is the same as the channel you created before"""

        return message.content.upper() in ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'] # Put all the valid moves here

    message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    # from here do your thing, add the moves, check if someone won the game, etc...
```

Can't be more specific without a code snippet of what you currently have